# Update collection and send email if conditions are met || Mongo Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a following case - I want to loop over every element in db and:

- if element has `bumped` field set to `false`
- and date of creation is less than 30 days ago

then:

- set `bumped` to `true`
- send mail to user!

#### My approach:

```
User.updateMany(
     {
        bumped: false,
        creationDate: {
           $gte: new Date(Date.now() - 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
        },
     },
     {
        $set: {
           bumped: true,
        },
     },
     (err, res) => {
        // 
        // What is "res" here? <====== question
     },
  );
```

My **question** - what is the `res` argument in the callback function?

**Question2**: will callback be fired only for these elements, which met the condition?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`updateMany` function doesn't return the updated documents. It only returns the number of documents updated.

So only thing you can do here is first find all the documents and  iterate one by one and then can call send mail function.

```
const users = await User.find({
  "bumped": false,
  "creationDate": {
    "$gte": new Date(Date.now() - 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
  }
})

const promises = users.map(async(user) => {
  await User.updateOne({ _id: user._id }, { $set: { bumped: true }})
  // Here you can write your send mail function
})

await Promise.all(promises)
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I think that `const users = User.find(...)` does not need `await` keyword. Or Im wrong? Even compiler is complaining about it - "Await has to be used inside Async function"

Comment: You should use await only with `async` function